# check istio installed option value

Tags: istio

I have istio environment, I want to know this option value:
for eg:

```
  --set values.global.mtls.auto=true \
  --set values.global.mtls.enabled=false
```

how do I check istio installed option value?

Comment: You're looking for description of what a given command does or you want to check 
 if a given command worked after you applied it to your cluster?

Comment: I just want to print the option value use some command or other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many tries. I found command can get value.

```
pilot-discovery discovery -a default
```

```
},
    "outboundTrafficPolicy": {
        "mode": "ALLOW_ANY"
    },
    "enableAutoMtls": true,
    "trustDomain": "cluster.local",
    "trustDomainAliases": [
    ],
    "defaultServiceExportTo": [
        "*"
    ],
    "defaultVirtualServiceExportTo": [
        "*"
    ],
```